# Set parent title from child components in Reactjs

Tags: reactjs

Good evening, I have a doubt, how should I proceed to pass the name of the children page to the parent?

```
const AdminNoticePanel = ({pageName, children}) => {

const [name, setName] = useState("Administrar Noticias");

return(
    <div>
        <div className="block">
            <div className="panelContent-title">
                <i className="icon icon-title-small" /> {name} - {pageName}
            </div>


const AdminNoticeAddPanel = ({submitForm}) => {

const pageName = "TEST PAGE NAME";

const { handleChange,
    values, errors } = NoticeService(
    submitForm,
    ValidateForm
);
```

Answer (score 0):

The question is unclear but according to my understanding You have to declare state in `useState` in parent component and pass the setter function to child component then set it from child component.

Example:

```
Parent:
    const [name, setName] = useState(null);
Child:
    setName('xyz');
```